# Right way to install application as non-root

Tags: permissions, linux-mint, sudo

I have `/opt` owned by root

```
$ ls -al /opt
total 28
drwxrwxr-x  7 root  root  4096 Nov 23 11:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root  root  4096 Jun  8 21:53 ..
```

Need to install pycharm by extracting an achive to opt:

`tar xzf pycharm-professional-2022.2.4.tar.gz -C /opt`

I think it is better to have it created owned by the current user `light`.
I have added `light` to `root` group (both primary and supplementary) and added `w` permission to `/opt` but that doesn't allow him to modify opt:

```
$ id light
uid=1000(light) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),114(lpadmin),134(sambashare),136(libvirt)
```

If I run `sudo tar x... -C pycharm` then the directory is created owned by root.

So how to do it correctly?

Comment: *"I think it is better to have it created owned by the current user light."*: can you explain why? This is a very bad idea. you don't want application directories to be owned by non-root users.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is highly unsafe, and will likely break many programs that are expecting the user to have its own group as primary, notwithstanding that the root group has a lot more permissions than a normal group.

Revert all group changes and I highly suggest you to use [JetBrains Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) ([download](https://data.services.jetbrains.com/products/download?platform=linux&code=TBA)), which will deal with the non-root installation transparently

Comment: So everything should be installed as `root` ?